# Python - Animating large dataset with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, jupyter-notebook, visualization

For a personal project, I'm trying to animate a fairly large data set (1000 rows) to show multiple bird dives in Jupyter notebook. Eventually I'd also like to add subplots of acceleration data along with it.

I used simple examples as a rough template, such as the growing coil example in: https://towardsdatascience.com/animations-with-matplotlib-d96375c5442c

The code itself seems to run slow but fine, however it doesn't output an animation, just a static graph:
[image]

Here's my current code:

```
x = np.array(dives.index)
y = np.array(dives['depth'])
x_data, y_data = [], []

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 1000), ylim=(min(y),max(y)))
line, = ax.plot([], [])

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    x_data.append(x[i])
    y_data.append(y[i])
    line.set_data(x, y)

    return line,

plt.title('Bird Dives') 

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(
    fig, animate, init_func=init, frames= 1000, interval=50, blit=True)

ani.save('./plot-test.gif')
plt.show()
```

Is there a reason why it's just plotting a graph rather than an animated one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your error is in your `animate` function. You have `line.set_data(x, y)`, which is plotting the entire contents of `x` and `y` at every frame (and hence produces an animated graph that doesn't change).

What you intended to have in your `animate` function was `line.set_data(x_data, y_data)`.

As for performance: you can improve this by not creating an empty list and appending to it at every iteration. Instead its simpler to slice your original arrays `x` and `y`. Consider the following `animate` function instead:

```
def animate(i):
    line.set_data(x[:i], y[:i])
    return line,
```

Having said this, given that you've got a thousand frames it's still going to take a little while to run.

Comment: Ah I didn't realise that mistake I made in my function. The slicing method did also definitely speed up the process by a fair amount. Thanks a lot for you help!